# How safe is your data when it passes from your laptop to your 4G wifi hotspot?

Tags: encryption, privacy

I would like to create a private mobile hotspot on my smartphone that I will connect to with my laptop to do online banking.  My laptop will connect to my smartphone wirelessly, then my smart phone will transmit the data over the 4G network.

I use my (Android 8.0.0) smartphone quite liberally when it comes to surfing the web.  I don't navigate to any obviously dangerous/obscene sites, but I use it browse various sites like reddit, imgur, facebook, article sites, forums, etc.

I have a paid subscription to BitDefender which I use to scan my phone for malware.  What I'm worried about is potentially having some virus or malware on my phone that will spy on my laptop's data as it 'passes through' my phone before being put on the 4G network.  Is this possible?  Or is my laptop's data already encrypted before it arrives on my phone and thus 'shielded' from any potential malware on my phone?  Is the latest version of Bitdefender a reliable form of protection from my concerns?

Answer (score 3):

For Wi-Fi using the standard WPA2 Personal encryption, any device which knows the PSK (password) will be able to both sniff and inject data for any other device connected to that network. This means that a mobile phone, if connected to the same AP, will be able to tamper with connections from your laptop.

However, if you are connecting to a banking website which is using HTTPS, then it may not be a risk. If that is the case (which it really should be), then encryption will take place between your browser and the bank server, and your mobile phone will not be able to read or tamper with the connection.

Comment: Thanks for your response- I am indeed connecting to a bank's web application using https.  Could I then assume that the data is encrypted as it arrives to my phone, before then being sent over 4g?

Comment: @EkpBee Yes, it's encrypted before it goes over 4G.